# Howto obtain the root dom element of a bootstrap popover

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Suppose I show a bootstrap3 popover programmatically :

```
var p = $(#aButton).popover()
p.popover('show')
```

How can I obtain the root dom element of the popover ?

Not the popover of the element that triggered it, but 
the popover itself ?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you've set up your popovers,

```
$('#aButton .popover');
```

or

```
$('#aButton').next('.popover');
```

may work. In some cases, there's only one `.popover` in existence at a time.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it's done :

```
var p = $(#aButton).popover()

var popover = p.data('bs.popover')

vat theDomNodeOfThePopover = popover.tip()
```